# (stehen haben) combination

Tags: verb-usage

> Er wollte nichts in seiner Akte **stehen haben**.
>
> So wirst du nie alten Kaffee im Schrank **stehen haben**.

I can roughly understand the meaning of these two sentences but my question is: Is this the only combination of haben with another verb that exists or are there other combinations of haben with other verbs like liegen, sitzen, stecken, hängen?

Is there a grammar to back this (stehen haben) combination up?

Answer (score 2):

That construction *haben+Infinitiv* works great with all verbs that describe the way the subject is attached somewhere. Those are indeed *stehen, liegen, sitzen, stecken, hängen*, and some prefixed versions of those.

> Die Akte liegt mir vor. — Ich habe die Akte vorliegen.

> Dein Fahrrad steht im Weg. — Du hast dein Fahrrad im Weg stehen.

In colloquial German, you may use it for way more verbs.

> Er hatte die jeden Abend bei sich rumlungern.

It's always about the attachment.